# error converting string to JSON with RAD Studio

Tags: json, delphi, delphi-xe

I have this problem :

I recive strings with this format:

```
{
    {
        "name":"j1",
        "type":"12"
    },
    {
        "name":"j2",
        "type":"15"
    },
    .....
}
```

I would like to read data 
like get("name") and get(type) to read all data values  and show like

j1    12
j2    15
j3    23    and so on

I am using RAD studio ,firemonkey for mobile devices.

I wrote this code to parse the string to JSON an read it .

```
jo: TJSONObject;
jp: TJSONPair;
va1:TJSONvalue;
va2:TJSONvalue;

jo:= TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(TEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(a),0) as TJSONObject;

jp := jo.Get(1);
for i := 0 to jo.Size - 1 do
begin
    jp := jo.Get(i);
    Memo1.Lines.Add('ToString: ' + jp.ToString);
    Memo1.Lines.Add('JsonString: ' + jp.JsonString.Value);
    if (jp.JSONValue is TJSONTrue) or
            (jp.JSONValue is TJSONFalse) or
            (jp.JSONValue is TJSONNull) then
        Memo1.Lines.Add('JsonValue: ' + jp.JsonValue.ToString)
    else
        Memo1.Lines.Add('JsonValue: ' + jp.JsonValue.Value)
end;
```

When the program execute `jp := jo.Get(1);` I have this error "Access violation at adress 53605374 accessing address 0000013C"

I have tried other ways ... but I have not been able to solve the mystery.

Comment: I don't think that's valid JSON, so you might have to parse it yourself. Or at least manipulate it a little first before sending it to TJSONObject.

Comment: Think what happens when `jo.Size` is less than 2. `jo.Get(1)` would be invalid.

Comment: I'm not too experience with those encodings, but I think generally JSON is UTF-8, so I don't understand `TEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(a),`. But DavidA is right. This is not valid JSON. Are you sure you copied it in right? It would be valid if the outer curly braces would be square brackets. In that case you would have an array with two objects.

Answer (score 2):

According to [json.org](http://www.json.org/) this is not a valid json.

A valid json (validated [online](http://jsonlint.com/) ) would be:

```json
[
  {
    "name":"j1",
    "type":"12"
  },
  {
    "name":"j2",
    "type":"15"
  },
  .....
]
```

Or

```json
{
  data: [
    {
      "name":"j1",
      "type":"12"
    },
    {
      "name":"j2",
      "type":"15"
    },
    .....
    ]
}
```